# select * into query executeUpdate()

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am using postgresql with jdbc. When I try to use the following line of code it is'nt executing.

```
int suc = stins.executeUpdate("select * into kmeans_cluster"+i+" from kmeans_emp where sno="+sno);              
if(suc>0)System.out.println("success");
else System.out.println("fail");
```

the output is always "fail".

Here's the code snippet.

```
package kmeans;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Kmeans{
    Connection con;Statement st,stins;ResultSet rs;Scanner s;
    public Kmeans(){
        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/kmeans","postgres","naren");
            st = con.createStatement();
            stins = con.createStatement();
            s=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter no.of clusters");
            int nc = s.nextInt();
            float cc[]=new float[nc];
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from kmeans_emp");
            for(int i=0;i<nc;i++){
                rs.next();
                cc[i]=Float.parseFloat(rs.getString(3));
                int sno = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));                
                int suc = stins.executeUpdate("select * into kmeans_cluster"+i+" from kmeans_emp where sno="+sno);              
                if(suc>0)System.out.println("success");
                else System.out.println("fail");
            }
            float a,b;
            .
            .
            ...
```

Comment: Is a "select into" query supposed to return anything ?

Comment: What does this line output?

    int sno = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));

Comment: @Adrián serial number(primary key) of record in database

Comment: @wero I've checked the database and the record is'nt being inserted

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that? You should be using `create table .. as select ...` instead of the non-standard `select into` if you want to create  a new table. And neither `create table .. as select` nor `select ... into` returns the number of rows inserted into the new table

Comment: @Pradeep So you have tables kmeans_cluster0, kmeans_cluster1, etc and they have the same columns as table kmeans_emp?

Comment: @Adrián the `select * into` creates new table.So it's not necessary to define the tables before hand.